# auto-populate field in shiny webpage using URL

Tags: html, url, web, shiny

I have created a Shiny webpage page to enter data into database. I want to auto populate one field via url, so user doesn't have to fill information in that.

I am trying following

```
baseurl?email=navjot@gmail.com
```

but still it is not auto populating given field based on url.I have given correct id. is there any limitation on it in Shiny?